# What is the IN_HAS_NEXT state for GraphDB Queries?

Tags: graphdb

I noticed that I had a query stuck in the `IN_HAS_NEXT` state and I'm curious what its status means.

From the GraphDB SE Documentation 7.0 documentation,

[image: GraphDB D]

But I'm not entirely sure what that amounts to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN_HAS_NEXT means, that the engine is evaluating the solutions from the binding set iterator (hasNext()). In simple words this is the "where" part of the update query which prepares the results before commit. It might seems stuck if there are many returned results. If you are still experiencing problem with this query you can send an email, describing the problem, to graphdb-support@ontotext.com